# Как сделать, чтобы :hover не работал на мобильных экранах в @media?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы :hover не работал у тега (a) и тега (button).

Я нашёл решение в том, что нужно писать :hover отдельно в @media, а не в общих стилях. Но я не уверен, что это верный способ решения. Какие способы ещё есть?

Пример:
media (min-width: 1440px)
podcasts: hover {
color: #ff0000;

```css
.podcasts {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #121723
}

.podcasts:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lala" class="podcasts">Подкасты</a>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Можно подробнее описать проблему? И какой результат в итоге нужен?

Comment: Если Вы хотите, чтобы что-то работало на десктопе и НЕ работало в мобильной версии, Вам в любом случае придётся использовать медиа-запросы (они, собственно, для того и придуманы). И вариант, который Вы нашли, оптимальный.

Comment: @Maneken У меня на сайте сейчас работает hover на десктопной версии и на мобильной. Мне нужно, чтобы на мобильной версии сайта не работал hover, то-есть выключить его, а на десктопной версии продолжал работать. 

К примеру для экранов разрешения 720/320px псевдо класс hover не работает для атрибутов <a> и <button>. А для экранов 1440/1110px работает.

Comment: @humster_spb Ясно, спасибо

Comment: каким образом ховер может работать на мобильной версии, если нет указателя? через F12 все нормально работает и в мобильной версии не работает, так как вам нужно

Comment: @Maneken В мобильной версии после нажатия на ссылку, ссылка горит красным, а это значит что работает hover

Comment: вариант такой: прописать в @media a:hover color: white , ну такой же цвет указать как не активная и не будет эффекта никакого видимого, как буд-то не работает)

Comment: Я видел лишь вариант, где стили для `:hover` запихуют в `@media`, вы можете посмотреть вроде в сторону миксинов в sass/scss. Они сильно облегчат это дело.

Answer (score 0):

На мобильном устройстве нет такого понятия как *hover*, поскольку нет курсора, а соответственно и наведения никакого нет. Потому на мобильном устройстве (именно на устройстве) вы не увидите срабатывания данного условия.
Однако при отладке в devtool если вы "изменяете" устройство или его размер (в браузере) - вы можете наблюдать изменение при наведении. И в таком случае только медиа запросы помогают переназначить поведение. Что вы и осуществили.